# Removing Ubuntu 18.04 from boot after deleting ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi

I recently deleted the ubuntu 18.04 (edit: ubuntu in dual-boot mode) partition and its swap partition using **disk management** in windows 10. But there seems to be a problem with the boot and ubuntu still shows up in the boot sequence in BIOS and in advanced restart in windows (I have attached photos for reference). I do not have any pen drives containing ubuntu attached. I have no idea why that shows up.

I tried installing arch Linux yesterday and after a complete installation it didn't show any grub (just the minimal grub, but that was already there before) and neither did it show up in the BIOS boot options either.

[BIOS boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLTEC.jpg)

[Advanced boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvz6g.jpg)

Until recently I used to get Minimal bash version of grub2 on startup (even after deleting the partitions), but that got fixed when I tried `bootrec /fixboot` with a windows recovery drive.

**What I have tried**

- Start-up repair from the advanced boot options. *Didn't work*. It made a SrtTrail.txt log file which said "Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully." at the end.
- Command prompt from the same place. Tried `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`. *Didn't work*. `bootrec /fixboot` said, "Access is denied".
- Tried the last sequence of commands with a Windows recovery drive. *Worked Partially*. Minimal grub2 doesn't show up anymore.
- I tried searching on the internet for solutions, and none seem to work uptil now.

But Ubuntu still shows up as shown in the images linked above.

I don't know if this is useful, but when I sign into windows, it starts with CMD and a black screen and I have to start an "explorer" task manually

Does anyone know what is going on? Please let me know for any additional info.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :D

Edit: I have a Lenovo Ideapad 520 (Lenovo 81BF).
Edit 2: The ubuntu was dual-booted with Windows 10.

Comment: I haven't tried using a Ubuntu live OS and boot-repair. I'll try that and come back with an update.

Comment: I just tried doing that and it did not help. I still have the exact same problem.

Comment: Also, EasyBCD says I only have Windows 10 in the boot sequence. Just one option. But the BIOS still shows "ubuntu" as an option. I have no clue what's going on.  :/